# how to monitor JVM on cloud applications

Tags: jvm

we are using cloud applications say spark with jre1.8
i want to know JVM of my spark instance and same need to be monitored using nagios core server.
can you please share inputs to view JVM stats.
i noticed, jstat command will be used to know JVM but unfortunately jstat is not working on jre.

Answer (score 0):

you might want to check the "Metrics" section [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html)

Also this is the source configuration in the metrics.properties we are using to monitor jvm metrics in emr spark. The sink configuratuion is dependent whether you want to push those metrics to graphite or just use plain jmx for instance. From that point on you can use your favorite jmx client or jolokia to make those metrics available via http. Just be aware that there may be more than one jvm running on each of the servers (one for each executors, maybe hdfs or whatever else you deploy).

```
# Enable jvm source for instance master, worker, driver
master.source.jvm.class=org.apache.spark.metrics.source.JvmSource
worker.source.jvm.class=org.apache.spark.metrics.source.JvmSource
driver.source.jvm.class=org.apache.spark.metrics.source.JvmSource
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Jprofiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html) to monitor the server.